# Scale and move image down (off-screen) on scroll down the page

Tags: scroll, transform, scale, move

I have an image in a WordPress site that is positioned (absolute) to layer over a background video and under a text block (also position absolute). When a user scrolls down the page, I need the image to scale to 0 down to the bottom left corner. At the same time, a similar image appears in my navigation bar which is anchored to the bottom of the browser window and appears upon scroll. That effect currently works properly. The site is done in Divi and the image in question is a full-width image module. Everything I've tried within Divi's Scroll Effects has not yielded the proper effect. You can preview here: https://modusai.wpengine.com

Comment: All code you want us to look at must be here, in the question, as text.

Comment: Hi Greg. There is no code available for me to add yet because I'm doing this in Divi. That said, for those who stumble upon this - I was able to achieve the desired effect using Divi's Scroll Effects on a Fullwidth Image module! Will answer my question separately below.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the desired effect in Divi - I started with a Fullwidth Header section. In the Fullwidth Header module, I uploaded and added a video for the background. In the same section (yes, you can add more than one module to a Fullwidth section), I added a Fullwidth image and another Fullwidth Header. Both of those two modules are set to Absolute position (bottom left and center, respectively), with z-indexes of 299 and 499 respectively, to achieve the layered effect I needed.

Then, in the Fullwidth Image module, I enabled the Vertical Motion, Horizontal Motion, and Scaling Up and Down effects. Those settings are:
Vertical Motion: 18% / 48% / 78% and 0 / 7 / 15 
Horizontal Motion: 18% / 48% / 78% and 0 / -7 / -15 
Scaling: 18% / 48% / 78% and 100% / 50% / 0% 
All three have the Motion Effect Trigger set to "Bottom of Element"

The sample is currently at https://modusai.wpengine.com/  If you have any questions, ping me!